# SVGs are requested on mouse hover/move multilple times

Tags: angular

I have some images loads in an angular mat table row. When I disable the cache and hover the mouse over the row the SVGs load multiple times. ( ex; more than 6000 requests for 8s )

Why does it happens?

Comment: Looks like your component is rerendering while you moving the mouse above the table.

Comment: Recommend to check this video and try to debug your runtime https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8sA-i6gkGQ